# Element.innerHTML = html; outputs html but changed slightly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

somehow this code:

```
    document.getElementById("task").innerHTML = html;
```

changes the class of divs from html

I wrote some code that would add a div class with where the name of the class was either checked-true or checked-false based on a boolean and for some reason three times where its originally checked-false in the displayed html its checked-true.

Why would that happen?

Comment: That's because when reading `innerHTML` it is dynamically constructed from DOM, it's not the same static string that you assigned. HTML entities, doublequotes, lots of other changes may occur.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a value to `innerHTML` causes it to be parsed as HTML, turned into DOM and inserted into the document. The string value itself is not stored.

Reading from `innerHTML` causes the DOM to be serialized to HTML. The original string is not returned (and can't be as it isn't stored).

As a side effect of this, the HTML is normalised.

Comment: but why would it only change the class of these specific tags, everything else is left untouched